# How to secure MEX endpoint WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

suppose i have developed a WCF service with one mex endpoint. now i like to know how can i secure the mex endpoint means that if anyone know my mex endpoint address then that user may not be able to add my mex endpoint address from their VS IDE to create proxy. if user try to do so then windows auth login dialog comes.

now the question is how then any out side user will be able to call my wcf service. i will distribute my service dll or proxy class related *.cs files or WSDL. so user can add that dll or add those proxy related .cs file or add wsdl to their project to create proxy just to call & consume my service. i am not advance developer so i am not being able to understand how to develop this kind of secure wcf service where user can not add my mex endpoint.

so just guide me with little wcf sample code & config example from where i can understand what i need to to meet my requirement. thanks

Comment: WCF security is a pretty broad topic, entire books are written on it. I suggest finding and reading one of those books. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732362(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This topic looks helpful
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395212%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Initially, one would think one would just change the HTTP to HTTPS but according to the article apparently you lose some degree of freedom in configuration

> If you use the mexHttpsBinding your metadata endpoint will be secure, but there is no way to modify the binding settings.